# Group ROWS in array with same Identifier

Tags: php

How can I run this array below inside of a `foreach` loop and group the rows together that share the same `section_id`?

I've labeled all the rows and sections with comment blocks.

**This is the array**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( // Row 1
        [assessment_selection_id] => 63 
        [assessment_id] => 32 
        [section_id] => 1 // Section 1
        [question_id] => 1 
        [selection] => 2 
        [timestamp] => 1368160586 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( // Row 2
        [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
        [assessment_id] => 32 
        [section_id] => 2 // Section 2
        [question_id] => 1 
        [selection] => 3 
        [timestamp] => 1368160510 
   )
   [2] => Array ( // Row 3
        [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
        [assessment_id] => 32 
        [section_id] => 2 // Section 2
        [question_id] => 1 
        [selection] => 3 
        [timestamp] => 1368160510 
   ) 

   [3] => Array ( // Row 4
        [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
        [assessment_id] => 32 
        [section_id] => 2 // Section 2
        [question_id] => 1 
        [selection] => 3 
        [timestamp] => 1368160510 
   ) 
)
```

**Expected result**

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( // Section 1
        [0] => Array ( // Row 1 
            [assessment_selection_id] => 63 
            [assessment_id] => 32 
            [section_id] => 1 
            [question_id] => 1 
            [selection] => 2 
            [timestamp] => 1368160586 
        )
    )
    [1] => Array ( // Section 2
        [0] => Array ( // Row 1
            [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
            [assessment_id] => 32 
            [section_id] => 2 
            [question_id] => 1 
            [selection] => 2 
            [timestamp] => 1368160586 
        )
       [1] => Array ( // Row 2
            [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
            [assessment_id] => 32 
            [section_id] => 2 
            [question_id] => 1 
            [selection] => 2 
            [timestamp] => 1368160586 
        )
       [2] => Array ( // Row 3
            [assessment_selection_id] => 61 
            [assessment_id] => 32 
            [section_id] => 2 
            [question_id] => 1 
            [selection] => 2 
            [timestamp] => 1368160586 
        )
    )
)
```

**Expected result without array**

**Section 1**

- **Row 1**

  assessment_selection_id, 
  assessment_id, 
  section_id, 
  question_id, 
  selection, 
  timestamp

**Section 2**

- **Row 1**

  assessment_selection_id, 
  assessment_id, 
  section_id, 
  question_id, 
  selection, 
  timestamp
- **Row 2**

  assessment_selection_id, 
  assessment_id, 
  section_id, 
  question_id, 
  selection, 
  timestamp
- **Row 3**

  assessment_selection_id, 
  assessment_id, 
  section_id, 
  question_id, 
  selection, 
  timestamp

Comment: the first `[assessment_selection_id]` with `[timestamp] => 1368160586 ` should be 63, not 61 :)

Comment: Thanks, I think the main focus is on the section_id's being correct, but I'll address your issue.

Comment: Do you need to have the key for the sections as shown in your example or any other value for them could work?

Comment: I think ordering by a numerical key would be the best. But, it can always be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's think you have your array saved in $myArray
Do this:

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($myArray as $val){
    $newKey=$val['section_id'];
    $newArray[$newKey][]=$val
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: @SaVaFa would you give me an example that will echo the section name and rows out in php? Having some trouble for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

with little change in @SaVaFa's logic (as per Question author's desired output)
Array keys with String value (associative array)

```
$row = "section";
foreach($arrMain as $key){
    $sectionID=$key['section_id'];
    $arrResult[$row.$sectionID][]=$key;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($arrResult);die;
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [section1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 63
                    [section_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [section2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 61
                    [section_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 61
                    [section_id] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [assessment_selection_id] => 61
                    [section_id] => 2
                )

        )

)
```